# How to develop a SharePoint 2013 Event Receiver with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, development-environment, sharepoint-2013

I tried to configure a small development environment.

**OS**: Windows Server 2012 Standard

**SharePoint**: SharePoint 2013

**IDE**: Visual Studio 2012 (Update3)

**Tools**: Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 (via WebInstaller)

But If I open my VS2012 and try to create a new project for a event receiver the template for this is not there... I can just select an empty SharePoint 2013 project or some other templates but not event receiver...

Also with a online search I was not able to find this template. But If you follow this blog here then these templates should be available or not? Link: http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.de/2013/05/creating-simple-event-receiver-in.html

All programs (VS2012 and SharePoint 2013) are installed together on one computer.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? How can I get this template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an empty SP project and add Event Receiver to it from project items menu.

Comment: What a shame for me, omg... Many thanks for the tip. I didn't know that I first have to create an empty project and as second step to insert the event receiver. Many thanks again.